# Как написать метод, подсчитывающий среднее значение одного из свойств во всех экземплярах класса?

Tags: javascript

Есть класс User, который устанавливает возраст для каждого нового пользователя. Нужно написать метод averageAge(), который возвращает средний возраст всех созданных пользователей.

Я думаю (но могу ошибаться) это реализовывается через static, но не могу сообразить как именно. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
class User {
  constructor(age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
  
  get age() {
    return this._age;
  }
  
  set age(value) {
    this._age = value;
  }
  
  static averageAge() {
    // some code
  }
}

const john = new User(25);
const pete = new User(15);

User.averageAge();   // должно вернуть 20
```

Если возраст изменить, то averageAge пересчитывается.

```
pete.age = 19;

User.averageAge();   // теперь будет 22
```

Comment: У класса, кроме методов, могут быть и свойства, верно? Добавим счетчик созданных юзеров и их общий возраст. Средний возраст получим простым делением.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант...

```
class User {
    static a = []
    constructor(age) {
        User.a.push(age)
        this.age = age;
    }

    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }

    set age(value) {
        if (this._age != undefined) {
            const i = User.a.indexOf(this._age)
            if (i === -1) throw new Error('Проблема с возрастом') 
            User.a[i] = value
        }
        this._age = value;
    }

    static averageAge() {
        return User.a.reduce((c, v) => c + v) / User.a.length
    }
}

const john = new User(25);
const pete = new User(15);

console.log(User.averageAge());   // должно вернуть 20

pete.age = 19;

console.log(User.averageAge());   // теперь будет 22
```

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал совет что давали в комментарии к вопросу, без массива

```
class User {
    static st = {cnt: 0, sum: 0}
    constructor(age) {
        ++User.st.cnt
        this.age = age;
    }

    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }

    set age(value) {
        User.st.sum += this._age === undefined ? value : value - this._age
        this._age = value;
    }

    static averageAge() {
        return User.st.cnt ? User.st.sum / User.st.cnt : null
    }
}

const john = new User(25);
const pete = new User(15);

console.log(User.averageAge());   // должно вернуть 20

pete.age = 19;

console.log(User.averageAge());   // теперь будет 22
```